# F# Remove/Replace char in a specific string index

Tags: string, replace, f#

I want to remove a char in a string. but not all the elements of that char in a string. example. i want `"|red|red|red|red|"` to turn into `"red|red|red|red"` So I want to create a function that checks if the first and last index of a string is a certain char and remove it if its the case.

so far i have come up with something like this:

```
let rec inputFormatter (s : string) : string =
    match s.[1] with
    |'|'|','|'.'|'-' -> // something that replaces the char with "" in the string s
                        (inputFormatter s)
    |_ -> match s.[(String.length s)] with
          |"|"|","|"."|"-" -> // same as above.
                              (inputFormatter s)
      |_ -> s
```

Can anyone help me figure out what i could write in my function? Ofcourse you are also welcome to come up with an etirely different function if you find that more conveniet.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the existing ``.Replace`` method of the string instance?

Comment: because that removes all the elements of the char in the string? if i go s.Replace("|", "") then it will remove all the pipes in the string

Comment: Combine [string.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx), [string.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx) with [string.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can you illustrate Mark? When i try then i just get an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let replace elem (str:string) =    
    let len = String.length str
    if str.[0] = elem && str.[len-1] = elem then str.[1..len-2]
    else str
```

Usage:

```
replace '|' "|red|red|red|red|"

// val it : string = "red|red|red|red"
```

And here's a version working with string instead of char:

```
let replace elem (str:string) =    
    let lens = String.length str
    let lene = String.length elem    
    if lene <= lens && str.[0..lene-1] = elem && str.[lens-lene..lens-1] = elem then str.[lene..lens-lene-1]
    else str
```

**UPDATE**

As Mark suggested a better option is re-using `Trim`

```
let replace (elem:string) (str:string) = str.Trim(elem.ToCharArray())
```

Comment: Why not use [string.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up using Gutavo's fix but it was him that inspired me to fix my own function!

```
let rec theButcher (s : string) : string =
    match s.[0] with
    |'|'|','|'.'|'-'|' ' -> (theButcher s.[1..])
    |_ -> match s.[(String.length s)-1] with
          |'|'|','|'.'|'-'|' ' ->  (theButcher s.[0..((String.length s)-2)])
          |_ -> s
```